# Setting up triggers in MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger where a new record populates in another table when I enter data into table "employee." However, I am getting an error. Here is the trigger I have so far:

```
Create trigger empaftertrigger after INSERT ON employee
FOR EACH ROW      
Insert into tbl_employee_audit (emp_id, audit_data) values (new.emp_id, "New employee with ID "new.emp_id "was added on " NOW());
```

Error:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'new.emp_id "was added on " NOW())' at line 3

*I must have the new.emp_id populate in between the string that is supposed to enter the column for audit data.* Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: `"New employee with ID "new.emp_id "was added on "` seems to be the culprit. Can you create a SQL fiddle with your tables or share their definition here? That would clarify your schema and the intention.

Comment: Thanks for the response Lajos. I am still new to MYSQL as a whole, so I has to look up SQL fiddle when I saw your response. I did not use queries to generate the tables as I used phpmyadmin. I have submitted the exercise as is hoping to get some clarification from my colleagues and instructor. Thank you!

Comment: concat('New employee with ID ', new.emp_id , 'was added on ', NOW()

Comment: Adeliz, you can run `show create table tbl_employee_audit;` and `show create table employee;` in PHPMyAdmin. It will forward these commands to MySQL and it will give you the exact schema. Can you edit your question and add these results to it? Thanks!